# obfuscating strings.xml file in android app

Tags: android, apk, proguard, obfuscation

I have obfuscated my code using ProGuard and generated a signed apk.

I then decompiled the generated apk file to verify obfuscation. However I could not find the strings.xml file! (res\values\strings.xml)

Does proguard hide/destroy the strings.xml file? If not, where can I find it in the decompiled apk?

thanks.

Comment: Couldn't find it either, when i decompiled an app

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075404/proguard-is-not-obfuscating-strings-xml-in-android.

Answer (score 0):

proguard does not hide strings, but [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard) can do that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case ProGuards obfuscates `res/values` folder, and it doesn't exist in `res` folder of an apk. I could only find a required string inside `resources.arsc`, see [Android compiled resources - resources.arsc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548810/android-compiled-resources-resources-arsc). It is binary, so it has some trouble to search a needed string inside it.